# Vertical scrollbars cause frame to strobe and flicker constantly

Tags: lubuntu, lxqt, widgets, scrollbar

I recently upgraded Fadein Pro from a 3.x version to 4.0.13. When I open the editing window, it pulls up the screenplay but the page constantly flickers, as if the window is refreshing with and then without the vertical side scrollbar. The effect is like a flashing strobe. Impossible to work or write when it's dancing around like that.

Luckily, there's an option to disable the scrollbar in Preferences, which works, and the screen is fine when that's selected. Nice stable page. But to get from one end of a 100 page screenplay to the other is a lot of scrolling of the mouse wheel.

I am running Lubuntu 20.04LTS, and have a hunch that the issue is caused by something in the widget rendering or incompatibility with LXQt. I think it's somehow hiding, then showing, then hiding, then showing the vertical scrollbar, refreshing the frame each time.

Does anyone know what might be going on here? Thank you!

Comment: If the problem only occurs on one version of one application, the problem is probably with the application, not the OS.

Comment: Sorry, @guiverc, you are right.  I am on 20.04LTS, so if that uses LXQt, then I'm wrong in the original explanation.  I've amended it to say LXQt.  Hope that helps.

Nmath Yes, entirely possible.  Just hoping there is a way I can solve it at my side.  Fingers crossed.

Comment: I know nothing about *Fadein Pro*, thus what toolkits/libraries and what settings it draws on (is it Qt5? like the LXQt desktop is, is it GTK3/4? etc) and I gather it's not a Ubuntu/Debian package found in repositories thus cannot easily look what settings it'll use. I'd thus suggest experimenting with changing your appearance defaults; https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.2/appearance.html in the manual is where I'd probably start (if not a `apt-cache depends` request if you have it installed as a *deb* package in your sources) - but I'm guessing sorry.

Comment: Thank you, @guiverc, no fault for "guesses" and I'll see if that helps.  Thank you
!

Comment: Tried installing it with apt-get and checked all the "depends" list, no dice.  Thanks for the suggestion.